# How does P2P multiplayer work without port forwarding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ip, p2p

I'm just trying to understand the title, basically. I understand how client/server relationships work, for example, using the socket module in python. A server is hosted somewhere, the router there forwards a port to be handled by the machine that is hosting the server, and the clients connect to the server. Games like Overwatch and Minecraft (although you have to host the server yourself) use this setup as I understand

P2P of course, the peers all act as both server and client to each other. As I understand, Deep Rock Galactic uses this method. But how do the clients connect to each other without port forwarding? Why and how are their requests not blocked at their router's public IP? How can this be emulated?

If someone could explain that, preferably with a demonstration of a simple p2p connection using python sockets, I would be very grateful

Comment: The easiest solution is that two peers can simply swap roles. First A tries to connect to B, and if that fails then B tries to connect to A.  If that still fails, then you have to fall back to more complicated solutions, like NAT Traversal or Hole Punching, or routing through a central server C, etc. There is plenty of documentation floating around on P2P techniques if you search around.

Comment: Wouldn't A -> B and B -> A always fail unless one of them is port forwarding? Also, if you're familiar, could you quickly explain or leave some resources on NAT Traversal and Hole Punching? I also spoke with a friend of mine today, that mentioned there is a way to "initiate" the P2P using a central, port forwarded server, as you said, but I'd prefer to avoid this in my uses if possible as my only option for it has a motherboard that is probably older than I am. Thank you. @RemyLebeau

Comment: "*Wouldn't A -> B and B -> A always fail unless one of them is port forwarding?*" - yes, if both client and server are behind their respective NATs. That is where other techniques then come into play. "*could you quickly explain or leave some resources on NAT Traversal and Hole Punching?*" - there are plenty of resources readibly available online if you search around. This is a very complex topic, there are whole research papers on it.

Comment: Check the related tab on the right of this question, maybe. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65335945/12101554 https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643830/12101554 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926029/12101554